# JS should mantain it work after page reload

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I am basically complete zero in JS,  so this question might be completely dumb, anyway…
I have a script that shows filename in bootstrap4  file input

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#custom-file-input

This script is in charge for showing the file name inside   the  input:

[image]

Problem is when page gets reloaded (due to the form failed validation, for example), this field would turn itself empty, that is without file name in it.
Is it possible to modify this script in a way to show filename after page gets reloaded?
P.S. Files are there after reloading. They are  cashed by backend.
file input html code is bellow {% endif %}

```html
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '.custom-file-input', function (event) {
        $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(event.target.files[0].name);
    })
</script>

{% if widget.is_initial %}
    <a href="{{ widget.value.url }}"><img class="ml-0" src="{% thumbnail widget.value "small"  %}"></a>

    {% if not widget.required %}
    {% endif %}
    <br>

{% endif %}

<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile02" id="inputGroupFile02" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" {% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
        <label class="custom-file-label " for="inputGroupFile02">{{ widget.value|default_if_none:"Choose the file" }} {{ widget.filename }}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Steven B. This problem(keep file in the form)  is solved already. by file_resubmit app. All i need is to display file name in a field

Comment: Maybe you can save this name in `localStorage` or something similar to just pull it from there if it exists and populate the field again

Comment: @IvanS95 i can definetelly but it is half-page code. Guess it should be quick DRY soulytion by JS. I cant even read it,so thats why i ask community

Comment: Do client side validation, then allow the submit. But also do server side validation. If it fails server side but passes client side, assuming they are the same validation method, that means someone is trying to mess with your code (or has javascript disabled). Client side makes validation faster and a better response for the user, server side protects the server/data etc.

Comment: @imvain2  .Will not work due to the DJANGO requires data get submited in order to get self.clean_data for cross fields validdation. If it had been only single field validation - it whould have been much easier.

Comment: You are talking about server side validation. However, you can still capture the  submit event of the form in jquery/javascript , validate the fields that way and show an alert for any errors if no errors allow the form to submit to DJANGO and allow it to do its thing server side.

Comment: OK, thank you all. Problem is solved by Django code. had to tweak widget for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you not showed the whole code, full form and backend view. As per my understanding what I can suggest you is if you want to keep the file name even after page reload. You store that in session in your view like this:

```
   request.session['file']=reques.FILES
```

and in your template you can get this session variable like this to put it at the place of file name:

```
{{request.session.file}}
```

Comment: Thats might be the case but all action happens inside widget and i have already changed widgets code to get the same result. If you are interested i have added it to the question (check above)